Is there a rule-of-thumb for when a first-person singular verb will get a "-у" vs the more common "-ю" suffix?
According to the OpenRussian database, ~72% of non-reflexive first-person singular verbs get the "-ю" suffix. The overwhelming majority of the remaining first-person singular verbs in the database get the "-у" suffix.
Furthermore, some words even get a "-ую" suffix, eg. "чувствовать" -> "чувствую".
Is there a rule-of-thumb for determining when the stem will receive a "-ю", "-у", or "-ую" suffix?
I know that the ending of the stem often dictates which suffix is used when conjugating.

That inflectional ending is simply /-u/.
When verb stem ends with /j/, then /j-/ + /-u/ results in /ju/ which is written with letter "ю" in Cyrillic alphabet.
E.g. verb име́ть has present-tense stem /imʲej-/ and past-tense stem /imʲe-/:

име́ю /imʲej- + -u/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьměj-ǫ)
име́ешь /imʲej- + -ʲeʂ/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьměj-eši)
име́ет /imʲej- + -ʲet/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьměj-etь)
име́ем /imʲej- + -ʲem/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьměj-emъ)
име́ете /imʲej- + -ʲetʲe/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьměj-ete)
име́ют /imʲej- + -ut/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьměj-ǫtь)
име́ющий /imʲej- + -uɕːij/ (present active participle)

E.g. verb идти́ has present-tense stem /id-/ and past-tense stem /ʂed- ~ ʂ(o)-/ (/ʂed-/ is earlier form, from Proto-Slavic *šьd-):

иду́ /id- + -u/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьd-ǫ)
идёшь /id- + -ʲoʂ/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьd-eši)
идёт /id- + -ʲot/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьd-etь)
идём /id- + -ʲom/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьd-emъ)
идёте /id- + -ʲotʲe/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьd-ete)
иду́т /id- + -ut/ (← Proto-Slavic *jьd-ǫtь)
иду́щий /id- + -uɕːij/ (present active participle)

(Infinitive is usually formed from past-tense stem, but идти́ is an exception.)

+1, though иметь is probably not the best example. It was athematic in Proto-Slavic (its stem ended in -m) and its conjugation pattern was completely different from the modern Russian.

I believe source is in word infinitive:
"Идти" -- "иду"
"Любить" -- "люблю"
"Путешествовать" -- "путешествую"
"Чувствовать" -- "чувствую"
"Ковать" -- "кую"


Если при спряжении в основе глагола приходит чередование суффикса  ОВА/ЕВА на У/Ю, то в 1-м лице глагол оканчивается на УЮ/ЮЮ:

рисовать — рисую (тверд. согл.), горевать — горюю (мягк. согл.), ночевать — ночую (шипящий).

Если перед окончанием находится гласный, то окончание Ю:

читать — читаю, уметь — умею,  строить — строю, чуять — чую.

Если перед окончанием находится согласный, то выбор зависит от его твердости/мягкости:

велеть — велю,  гореть — горю (мягкие),
брать — беру, жить — живу (твердые),
дышать — дышу, хотеть — хочу (шипящие).

Here is how it was explained to me, a native English speaker learning Russian from a native Russian teacher:
Regarding first person singular, for first conjugation verbs, you use ю if the stem ends with a vowel or a soft sign and you use у after consonants.
For second conjugation verbs, you use ю if the stem ends in a soft consonant or a vowel and you use у after ж, ш, щ, ч, and all hard consonants.
So it isn't exactly a simple rule of thumb but it hasn't failed me yet.
